# How to remove elements of a .csv file based on another .csv file?

Tags: r, csv

I'm doing a script for kew-word finding in a text (in R language). For now I can only get a .csv (abstract_atomized.csv) list of words atomized and classified according to their frequency. I have another .csv list with the set of common and useless english words (wordlistenglish.csv) that I would like to remove from my first list in order to keep only the relevant elements. I do not know how I could do this effectively on R. Could you help me?

Thanks.

```
    library(pubmed.mineR)
    library(scholar)
    library(tools)
    library(stringr)
    abstractR <- readabs(abstract)
    atomized_text <- word_atomizations(abstractR)
    file_without_ext <- file_path_sans_ext(abstract)
    atomized_file_name <- paste0(file_without_ext, '_atomized.csv')
    write.csv(atomized_text, atomized_file_name)
    output_text <- paste0('Most used words described in ',atomized_file_name,' take the time to read them and to select the relevent key words')
    print(output_text)
abstract_atom<- read.csv('abstract_atomized.csv')
wordlist<- read.csv('wordlistenglish.csv')
abstract_atom[!(abstract_atom$words %in% wordlist$words),]
write.csv(abstract_atom, file='abstract_atom.csv')
```

Update

data structure (I can't put the entire structure because there are too many characters : around 6000 words for the first list and a thousand for the second)

atomlist structure :

```
    words = structure(c(2772L, 4003L, 737L, 2371L, 3797L, 4988L
    ), .Label = c("-29", "-325", "-328", "-337", "-59", "-dependent", 
    "-dichlorophenyl)-1", "-disulfonic", "-induced", "-maleimidyldistilbene-2", 
    "-sh", "-so(3)(-))", "\"giacomo", "\"paradox", "(-323", "(-335", 
    "(-s-)", "(-so(-))", "(-so(2)(-)", "(#)contributed", "(1)department", 
    "(1)institut", "(1)instituto", "(1)laboratoire", "(1)laboratory", 
    "(1)plant", "(1)unité", "(10)laboratory", "(2-cys", "(2)bio-pharmaceutical", 
    "(2)department", "(2)sorbonne", "(2)université", "(219)cgpc(222)", 
    "(28)wcsys(32)", "(3)institute", "(3)laboratoire", "(3)laboratory", 
    "(3)plant", "(3d)", "(4)laboratoire", "(4)laboratory", "(4)sorbonne", 
    "(5)bio-pharmaceutical", "(5)department", "(6)laboratoire", 
    "(6)laboratory", "(6)plant", "(7)laboratoire", "(7)laboratory", 
    "(7)spemann", "(8)laboratory", "(8)université", "(9)laboratoire", 
    "(a(4)", "(a(4)-gapdh)", "(and", "(arabidopsis", "(aromatic", 
    "(atprk)", "(b-containing", "(bio-phase)", "(biogssg)", "(bioss)", 
    "(c86)", "(cb)", "(cr)", "(crpgk1)", "(crprk)", "(crtk)", 
    "(crtkapo)", "(cx(2)c)", "(cys(149)-ssg)", "(cys(29))", "(cys(87))", 
    "(dcmu)", "(deduced", "(diamide", "(e", "(e(m))", "(eda)", 
    "(eeg)", "(er)", "(fd)", "(for", "(frias)", "(ftr)", "(gapc1", 
    "(gapdh)", "(glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate", "(glycine", "(gpxs)", 
    "(grx)", "(grxs)", "(gsh)", "(h2o2)", "(heat-shock", "(hsp70", 
    "(i", "(icl)", "(inra)", "(isoform", "(lhcii)", "(metso)", 
    "(mms)", "(msrs)", "(multifunctional)", "(nadp-mdh)", "(negative", 
    "(no)", "(o2*)", "(pdi)", "(pgk1)", "(phaseolus", "(pk(a)=5", 
    "(pm)", "(populus", "(prk)", "(prxii)", "(prxs)", "(ptm)", 
    "(real", "(reduced", "(rns)", "(ros)", "(sll1621)", "(sll1908)", 
    "(slr1562", "(slr1849)", "(sno)", "(sorghum", "(spinacia", 
    "(ss)", "(ssg)", "(tk)", "(tpi)", "(tpp)", "(trx", "(trx)", 
    "(trx)-dependent", "(trxf)", "(trxh1)", "(trxh2)", "(trxs)", 
    "(upmc)", "(β/α)8-barrel", "[(35)s]cysteine", "[4fe-4s]", 
    "[fe2s2]", "[gsh]/[gsno]", "[gsh]/[gssg]", "&", "+/-", "+300", 
    "+80", "<2-fold", "~10-fold", "~20-fold", "~6-fold", "06", 
    "1-cys", "1-dimethylurea", "10 μm", "1052", "11", "110", 
    "1136", "1188", "119", "12", "125", "1278", "13", "133", 
    "1417", "16", "18", "190", "2-cys", "2-cys-peroxiredoxin", 
    "2)", "200", "225", "24", "25", "26", "29", "2nd", "3-(3", 
    "3-bisphosphoglycerate", "3-phosphoglycerate", "30", "33", 
    "381", "383", "392", "3d", "3d-structure", "3rd", "4-acetamido-4", 
    "40126", "41092", "42", "492", "54506", "55", "56", "561", 
    "7)", "70 kda)", "70803", "75005", "79104", "81", "8226", 
    "86", "8600", "8618", "9)", "90", "90095", "91405", "94720-3102", 
    "98%", "å", "a(2)b(2)", "a(4)-gapdh", "a(4)-glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate", 
    "a(8)b(8)", "a(n)b(n)-gapdh", "aa", "ab", "åb", "abdelmohsen", 
    "abe", "abedin", "abeliovich", "ability", "abiotic", "able", 
    "abnormally", "absence", [...] "zhong", "zhou", "zhu", "zhuang", 
    "zimmer", "zio", "ziparo", "zj", "zm", "zn", "zois", "zoladek", 
    "zong", "zorzano", "zughaier", "zw", "zx", "β-sheet"), class = "factor"), 
    Freq = c(161L, 150L, 114L, 98L, 90L, 79L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

wordlist structure

```
structure(list(the = structure(c(8762L, 9971L, 9929L, 9917L, 
9628L, 9437L), .Label = c("a", "aa", "aaa", "aaron", "ab", "abandoned", 
"abc", "aberdeen", "abilities", "ability", "able", "aboriginal", 
"abortion", "about", "above" [...] "yukon", "z", "za", "zambia", "zdnet", "zealand", "zen", "zero", 
"zimbabwe", "zinc", "zip", "zoloft", "zone", "zones", "zoning", 
"zoo", "zoom", "zoophilia", "zope", "zshops", "zu", "zum", "zus"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: To get an answer and prevent your question being down-voted you really need to provide some of the code from your attempt at solving this

Comment: yes thank you I update my post right now

Comment: The code you included here seems to already incorporate my solution. Is that correct? Is there still a problem after you added it?

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to precise that this is the corrected code. And unfortunately yes it doesn't work. The first list keeps the unwanted words contained in the second list.

Comment: Note that you're not assigning the filtered data.frame anywhere, so when you `write.csv`, you're writing the original `abstract_atom` data.frame. Add `abstract_atom<-` before the filtering line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the general format you should use, adapted to your actual data structure:

```
filtered_list<- list1[!(list1$words %in% list2$words),]
```

It keeps all rows in `list1` in which the word does not appear in `list2`. If you want to do this using the tidyverse (which is slower, but often more convenient to code in), it will look like this:

```
require(dplyr)
filtered_list<- list1 %>% filter(!(words %in% list2$words))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But strangely it doesn't remove the row that are in list2 (wordlistenglish.csv).

Comment: Like I said - this needs to be adapted to the actual data structure. If you could provide the `dput(head())` for both of your lists, it should be easy to adapt the solution to them.

Comment: Ok here is the structure for ````atomlist```` : ````structure(list(X = c(2820L, 4068L, 765L, 2418L, 3862L, 5081L), 
    words = structure(c(2772L, 4003L, 737L, 2371L, 3797L, 4988L
    ), .Label = c("-29", "-325", "-328", "-337", "-59", "-dependent", 
    "-dichlorophenyl)-1", "-disulfonic", "-induced", "-maleimidyldistilbene-2", 
    "-sh", "-so(3)(-))", "\"giacomo", "\"paradox", "(-323", "(-335", 
    "(-s-)", "(-so(-))", "(-so(2)(-)", "(#)contributed", "(1)department", 
    "(1)institut", [...]````

Comment: And here for ````wordlist````: ````structure(list(the = structure(c(8762L, 9971L, 9929L, 9917L, 
9628L, 9437L), .Label = c("a", "aa", "aaa", "aaron", "ab", "abandoned", 
"abc", "aberdeen", "abilities", "ability", "able", "aboriginal", 
"abortion", "about", "above", "abraham", "abroad", "abs", "absence", 
"absent", "absolute", "absolutely", "absorption", "abstract",[...] ````

Comment: I can't really use that. Can you put the full output in your question?

Comment: I added it to my post. But I can't put the full structures because of their sizes.

Comment: Oh, why are the word lists in factors? Replace the data you posted with the output from `dput(droplevels(head(list1)))` (and list 2)

Comment: Thank you again for your help.  atomlist````structure(list(X = c(2820L, 4068L, 765L, 2418L, 3862L, 5081L), 
    words = structure(c(3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("c", 
    "j", "m", "redox", "s", "y"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(161L, 
    150L, 114L, 98L, 90L, 79L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")````
wordlist````structure(list(the = structure(c(1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("t", 
"v", "w", "x", "y", "z"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")````

Comment: Well, right off the bat the column name for the words list in `wordlist` is `the`, so in the code it should be `... %in% wordlist$the`. Then the code you provided above should work fine.

Comment: I saw this error too in my .csv file which is now fixed. It works great ! Thank you very much